# How can I put my text in a list?

Tags: javascript

```
function popup() 
{
    alert (
        "I will tell the truth. I will write deliberately and with accuracy."
        + " I will acknowledge and correct mistakes promptly.  I will preserve"
        + " the original post, using notations to show where I have made changes"
        + " so as to maintain the integrity of my publishing. I will never delete"
        + " a post. I will not delete comments unless they are spam or off-topic."
        + " I will reply to emails and comments when appropriate, and do so promptly."
        + " I will strive for high quality with every post – including basic spellchecking."
        + " I will stay on topic. I will disagree with other opinions respectfully."
        + " I will link to online references and original source materials directly."
        + " I will disclose conflicts of interest. I will keep private issues and topics" 
        + " private, since discussing private issues would jeopardize my personal and work"
        + " relationships.");
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Why put this text in a list? What kind of list?

Comment: @eakron I wanna be able to show my text in a list <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do only one thing in `alert()`, add `\n` which will put the text in newline.

```
alert ( "I will tell the truth. \n I will write deliberately and with accuracy. \n I will acknowledge and correct mistakes promptly.......")
```

If you want to apply HTML and styles then go for DHTML box (like lightbox, fancy box...)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Its displaying the text correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

> alert("I will tell the truth. I will write deliberately and with accuracy. I will acknowledge and correct mistakes promptly. I will preserve the original post, using notations to show where I have made changes so as to maintain the integrity of my publishing. I will never delete a post. I will not delete comments unless they are spam or off-topic. I will reply to emails and comments when appropriate, and do so promptly. I will strive for high quality with every post – including basic spellchecking. I will stay on topic. I will disagree with other opinions respectfully. I will link to online references and original source materials directly. I will disclose conflicts of interest. I will keep private issues and topics private, since discussing private issues would jeopardize my personal and work relationships.".split('. ').join('.\n'));

It doesn't involve the process of putting newline after each statement manually. The above code does this action itself.

Comment: What error are you getting? Mention it specifically.

Comment: Nothing happens the hole page is blank ...